# How quickly toggle smart quotes in Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-word-2010, smart-quotes

I'm working on a long technical document that contains numerous displays of computer code. In running text, I want my quotation marks to be curly, which means that Word's "smart quotes" autoformatting-as-I-type feature is one I want on. But in code displays, curly quotes are incorrect, so in these cases, I want smart-quotes-as-I-type disabled. Is there a fast way to toggle this setting? Or is there a way I can tie it to the paragraph style I'm in?  (I use a distinct style for code displays.)

Currently, to toggle the setting, I have to click File>Options>Proofing>AutoCorrect Options...>"Straight quotes" with "smart quotes">OK>OK, which is seven mouse clicks. Toggling it back is another seven mouse clicks.  Isn't there a faster way? A keyhboard shortcut to do the toggling or a toolbar button that would toggle it with a single click would be great. Having the setting depend on the paragraph style I was in would be even better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, here's the answer:

1. Go to `View` tab > `Macros` > `Record Macro`
2. Give the macro a name and assign it to a key / shortcut (key combination)
3. Record something (does not matter what, we will reset it in a moment). Click on `Macros` > `Stop Recording` to stop.
4. Repeat steps 1-3 in order to create another macro (so we have now 2 macros total).
5. Go to `View` tab > `Macros` > `View Macros`
6. Choose the first macro and click `Edit`
7. Delete all the lines inside the macro's code (it's Visual Basic) except the `sub Macro_Name()` and `End Sub`
8. Copy this line into the sub: `Options.AutoFormatReplaceQuotes = True`
9. Do the same to the other macro, but write `Options.AutoFormatReplaceQuotes = False` instead.

Ultimately, that's the code (you may have other names and/or descriptions for your macros):
 *Also note that in Visual Basic, `'` defines a comment line (usually it turns the line green), means that line will **not** be executed.*

```
 Sub ToggleQuotes1()
'
' ToggleQuotes1 Macro
' Smart Quotes
'
    Options.AutoFormatReplaceQuotes = True
End Sub
Sub ToggleQuotes2()
'
' ToggleQuotes2 Macro
' Regular quotes 
'
    Options.AutoFormatReplaceQuotes = False
End Sub
```

P.S - There are two smart qoutes options under proofing. One is under the `AutoFormat` tab and the other is `AutoFormat as you type`. Here I've changes the first one, but the second one goes like that:
`Options.AutoFormatAsYouTypeReplaceQuotes = True
    Options.AutoFormatAsYouTypeReplaceQuotes = False`

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much!  I'm going to mark this as the answer, but before I do, I'm hoping you'll tell me how I can add these macros to my toolbar... (A link to how to do it would be fine.)

Comment: [I think that will do](http://superuser.com/questions/297197/microsoft-word-2010-custom-macro-buttons-without-writing-code) - just choose `Macros` under `Choose commands from`

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with only one macro containing the line

Options.AutoFormatAsYouTypeReplaceQuotes = Not Options.AutoFormatAsYouTypeReplaceQuotes

Comment: Cool enchantment! Better then my original solution.