# Word 2010, how to create a numbering list that has only 2 value such as Ask and Answer

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, text-formatting

I am a transcriber, in Word 2010 I want to create a list style that consists of just 2 prefixes: *Ask* and *Answer*; and it looks like this:

> **Ask:** Are u happy today?
>
> **Answer:** Nope, & you?
>
> **Ask:** Better than you. By the way, are you this and that and...?
>
> **Answer:** Yes, I am this and that.
>
> **Ask:** ....
>
> **Answer:** ...
>
> (...)

I have tried to play around with the define new number list, however, Word 2010 forces me to follow its number format (1,2,3...). How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

### Try this [guide](http://wordfaqs.mvps.org/QandA2007.htm).

Or, you can also try recording a macro:

1. Go to `View` tab > `Macros` > `Record Macro...`
2. Fill in the necessary information (name of the macro, description, and keyboard shortcut, if you want), and click `OK`.
3. Record yourself typing the Q&A template and style it (font, italics maybe, etc.).
4. Go to `Macros` > `Stop Recording` when you are done.

Now you can hit the hotkey you have configured in order to auto create the Q&A template.
You can also [configure a button to activate the macro](https://superuser.com/questions/297197/microsoft-word-2010-custom-macro-buttons-without-writing-code) (check the 2nd answer).

Comment: Thank you for your answers, but is there a way to apply the style for an existing document, because the guide above can only be used for new document.

Before asking this question, I copied and pasted the text into excel and used it to add the Ask and Answer part. However, I still prefer to be able to do this on existing docs in word 2010.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how a custom list style could alternate between two repeating words, you're not really making a list or numbering.  When I was a transcriber, I just assigned speakers to the function keys.  You could assign "Ask" and "Answer" to keys and just press them as you go.

The guide above where you commit styles to the individual paragraphs is also good, but I find that if you're still going to have to hit a key to apply styles, why not just add in the text you want?

Too much formatting for transcriptions can bite you when people try to import/export them into other software.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to create two styles which have a custom list style, one prefixed with "Ask" and the other "Answer". Assume these two names are the names of the styles. Set **Style for following paragraph** for the Ask style to Answer and vice versa for the Answer style.

This way when you finish writing a paragraph it will automatically switch to the other style when you press return.